# which Youtube APIv3 key should I create

Tags: youtube-api, windows-mobile, google-oauth

I build a windows app.

I use Youtube api v3, and it needs {MY_API_KEY}

In console developers web -> API&auth -> Credentials

there has two option, "OAuth" & "Public API access"

I think API key is created by "Public API access"

and it has 4 option,

> server key: My app doesn't run on server
>
> Android & iOS: my app is windows, so it's not this.

so should I create Browser key?

thx

Comment: Could you be more clear as to what you are doing?  1. are you accessing only public data?  is this a web application, windows application,  mobile application.

Comment: I just begin to do search video, without users login. if this complete, I want to get user's subscription, and that needs user login.  This is a mobile application

Comment: Use Installed application select type other.  recommend the .net client library https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.youtube.v3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only going to be accessing public data use a `Public API access` if like you say you will be accessing the users subscriptions you will need to be authenticated for that, and use Oauth2

Create a Client id -> installed application -> type other.

[image]

Also I recommend you look in to the [Google .net client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.youtube.v3/).

Comment: very thankful. But I only know C#. I've never learned .NET before. To Complete it, I must learn .NET?

Comment: I am pretty sure that C# is .net.  Unless I have completely missed something critical.

Comment: which is key? I create client id. have 3 field "Client ID", "Client secrect", "Redirect URls"

Comment: The key used in requests is an access token,  client id and client secret are used as part of Oauth2 to get a Refreshtoken and get an access token.  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

Comment: hi, Dalm. I have other problem now. I study this web https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth and I refer window 8.1's source code at bottom of web. But it needs client_secrects.json file. I don't have that. how to creater that file? or maybe I can write a json file and rename it.